# How to declare that a variable has the type of an array element in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typeof

In TypeScript, it is possible to declare that, e.g., `var b` has the same type as `var s`:

```
var s = "hello";
var b: typeof s;
```

Is there a simple way to declare that `var b` has the same type as the elements in an array? Here, `var b` should still be a string:

```
var c = ["hello", "world"];
var b: typeof(c[0]);
```

An ugly workaround (which runs even if `c` is null) is:

```
var c = ["hello", "world"];
var a = (<T>(x: T[]): T => null)(c);
var b: typeof a;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

No. There is no dedicated syntax for it. In the absence of a dedicated syntax you fundamentally need something that takes `T[]` and gives you `T`. You in-line function is a decent example of this generic usage.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything in the language specification about this, and to me this seems like something too trivial to be implemented; at least at the current stage that TypeScript is in.

However, a shorter/simpler workaround could be:

```
var a = 0 && c[0];
var b: typeof a;
```

Should work even if `c` is `null` or `undefined`.
Much less of a performance impact as well.